# How to find which brush was used in a layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, brush, history

In a new layer, I selected the shape of the letter U and used a specific brush to brush in that selection in Layer 16 (in the screenshot below).

Now I can't figure out which brush I used to get this hand-drawn effect. Is there a way to identify which brush is used in Layer 16, or is it hopeless? Thank you! I spent 20 minutes Googling this to no avail.

[image: Layer 16 has the brush I forgot]

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't think there's a specific feature for this. Your best bet would be to go back in the "History" panel (Window -» History) to see if you can bring the document back to when you were making the change.

I would suspect switching to the brush tool once reverted would give you the brush settings that were active at the time. Can't guarantee it'll work though.

Otherwise, I don't really see how that could be possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Go to History section and find it, or try your best Guess for brush name and google it,
Also if you are Pro try to create a new one brush for your needs.